# Installing python packages using pip on windows reci=eiving error 407 Proxy Authentication Required

Tags: python

```
Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after     connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required',))': /simple/peewee/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement peewee
  No distributions at all found for peewee
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please check out the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help as well as [the minimal verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  It sounds like something I could answer but you don't give enough information to help me answer it!

Comment: Ok am trying to download or install flask package on my pc and am using the cmd pip install Flask and its returning the above error

Comment: ... is that the exact error message you are getting? Please edit your question and format the error into a code block (highlight it and click the `{}` button on toolbar)

Comment: Yes thats the error am receiving.... am using a internet connection which uses a proxy so i want to know whether this might be the issue and how to solve

Comment: although I think you just need to run `pip --help` and see the note on the `--proxy` option

Answer (score 0):

according to `pip --help`:

```
--proxy <proxy>             Specify a proxy in the form
                            [user:passwd@]proxy.server:port.
```

so specifying a `--proxy` option may be all you need for pip to correctly use your proxy.